# JAR Hell error coming when upgrading from ES 1.x to ES 2.3.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am upgrading my ElasticSearch Plugin from ES 1.x to ES 2.3.5 . I made the required changes and build it using Maven. When I tried to install the plugin with ElasticSearch , it threw following error :

> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell! class:
>   javax.json.Json jar1:
>   C:\Users\ajaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\4537460277365737175\temp_name48813548
>   5\javaee-api-7.0.jar jar2:
>   C:\Users\ajaiswal\AppData\Local\Temp\4537460277365737175\temp_name48813548
>   5\javax.json-1.0.4.jar

I checked the binary generated from ES 1.x , it also contains the above 2 jars and binary is working fine. Why does this conflict occur in ES 2.3.5